# Почему это происходит?

Tags: c

В книге Пратта по Си есть этот пример.Я не особо понимаю, как он работает и не понимаю, зачем нужна эта функция.

```
char* s_gets(char* st, int n)
{
    char* ret_val;
    char* find;
    ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
    if (ret_val)
    {
        find = strchr(st, '\n');
        if (find)
            *find = '\0';
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n') // зачем нужна эта часть условия ?
                continue;

    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Помимо тех вопросов сверху возникает ещё один.
Например в функцию попадает вот такая строка: *"\n"*.
На скриншоте пошагово прохожу функцию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Почему изменение find меняет ret_val?***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопросам на SO принято давать более содержательные заголовки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `s_gets` призвана реализовывать следующую функциональность:

Читаем строку из стандартного входа в буфер длины `n`. Если строка в стандартном входе не помещается в буфер длины `n`, то читаем сколько поместится и просто выбрасываем/игнорируем/пропускаем лишнюю хвостовую часть строки.

Индикатором того, что входная строка не поместилась в буфер, является отсутствие в прочитанном буфере символа `'\n'`. В такой ситуации функция выполняет "выбрасывание" лишнего хвоста строки. Что и реализуется циклом

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
  continue;
```

Использование `continue` в этом цикле ничего не дает - это не более чем какая-то стилистическая привычка автора кода. Можно было просто написать

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
  ;
```

Здесь, кстати, есть к чему придраться. Последняя строка во входном потоке может и не заканчиваться символом `'\n'`, а заканчиваться ситуацией "конец файла" (EOF). В данной функции надо было бы принимать во внимание и возможность возникновения EOF.

---

> Почему изменение find меняет ret_val?

Изменение `find` не меняет сам `ret_val`. Изменение символа, на который указывает `find`, меняет строку, на которую указывает `ret_val`, потому что `find` указывает внутрь этой строки.

Comment: что означает "выбрасывание" лишнего хвоста, если и так из-за буффера не поместилась часть строки ?И почему find указывает внутрь строки ret_val?Не вижу , где бы find такое делала.Она всего лишь принимает указатель на первое вхождение нужного символа,но не на всю строку.А хотя это и есть вся строка.Тогда остается только первый вопрос про выбрасывание

Comment: понял, эта штука читает символы пока не найдет символы новой строки,только один вопрос , этот getchar пробегает где-то по строчке ? во входных данных(буфере ?)

Comment: @Elvin: 1) Та часть строки, которая не поместилась в буфер, остается сидеть во входном потоке. Вот оттуда мы ее и "выцарапываем" этим циклом, т.е. вычитываем лишние символы "в никуда", по одному. 2) После `fgets` указатель `ret_val` указывает туда же, куда и `st`. Поиск символа при помощи `strchr` делается в строке, указываемой `st`. Т.е. указатель `find` будет указывать внутрь строки, указываемой `st` и `ret_val`.

Comment: "getchar пробегает где-то по строчке" - не понимаю вопроса. `getchar` ни по чему нигде не "пробегает". Он просто читает входной поток посимвольно.

Comment: ,continue заставляет очищать весь входной поток,даже если та больше одного символа?То есть возвращает в условие цикла

Comment: @Elvin: `continue` здесь вообще ничего не делает. Автор кода видимо просто не любит циклов с пустым телом. Поэтому он просто вписал туда `continue` как "наполнитель". Я подправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (getchar() != '\n') // зачем нужна эта часть условия ?
                continue;
```

если считанный символ не `Enter` то будет считываться следующий символ.